# Django Admin.py customize form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've following models:-

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class B(models.Model):
    row1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I've enabled `admin` module. Lets say I've added 3 objects of `A` with name values as `Roy`, `Jack`, `Joe`. So now while adding a new B object from the admin panel, the row `a` (which is a FK from A) has a drop-down value, with 3 values as `A object` (all same), which is very difficult to link. **Can I customize these values with the names from A ??**

I know I can create an `admin.py` file, and create a class such as this:-

```
class A_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
```

But this is only for displaying the information in the list, not while selecting the dropdown values. **How do I display the name from `A` while adding an object of `B`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my class as follow and it worked. :)

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```